# Bootstrap built in css not working in div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and trying to make the h1 and h3 tags Jane (Doette and Front-End Ninja) in my div uppercase and align right. There seems to be a conflict somewhere. Can someone help me debug this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Final Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="Udacity Logo" src="images/udacity-logo.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" "text-right" "text-uppercase">
                <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
                <h3> Front-End Ninja</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="main picutre of a giraffe" src="images/animals690x350.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Featured Image</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="A cute little cat looks on with head turned to the side" src="images/cats325x300.jpg">
                <h3>Cacho</h3>
                <p><a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" target="_blank">Check out beautiful Cacho</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="A gorilla sits and looks into the distance" src="images/gorilla325x300.jpg">
                <h3>Gorilla</h3>
                <p><a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" target="_blank">Check out this beastly creature</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="A cat stands with a atonished and frightend look" src="images/animals325x300.jpg">
                <h3>Gorilla</h3>
                <p><a href="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" target="_blank">Check out this blue eyed cat</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you provided your classes are wrong. Please provide like this

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
```

Comment: @JeffreyCunningham If it helps make it as Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem

```
<div class="col-md-6" "text-right" "text-uppercase">
```

It should be like that :

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/56by5x8t/)